# How can I factor a polynomial with multiple different exponent fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the polynomial $3x^{\frac{3}{2}} - 9x^{\frac{1}{2}} + 6x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$, which should factor to, $3x^{\frac{-1}{2}}(x - 1)(x - 2)$.

I have tried:

- factoring out 3

$3(x^{\frac{3}{2}} - 3x^{\frac{1}{2}} + 2x^{\frac{-1}{2}})$

- changing to radical forms

$3(x\sqrt{x} - 3\sqrt{x} + \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{x})$

- factoring out $\sqrt{x}$ from $x\sqrt{x} $ and $-3\sqrt{x}$

$3[(x - 3)\sqrt{x} + (\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{x})]$

However, I'm still unable to figure out how to factor it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you factor out the $3$, also factor out an $x^{-1/2}:$

$$3x^{-1/2}(x^2-3x+2).$$

Note that "factor out" means that each term inside is divided by $x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: I can really get rid of the middle exponent that way?

Comment: You can check the step by multiplying the $x^{-1/2}$ back in.